# Exibir somente parte do texto em uma página Html

Tags: php, html, laravel

Gostaria de exibir apenas parte de uma String que contém um texto.
Fazer um "Clique para ler mais", eu tentei com

```
substr
```

mas como eu não sei em qual caractere uma palavra termina ele corta o texto no meio das palavras, queria que ele cortasse o texto mas deixando as palavras inteiras. Tentei fazer

```
explode()
```

e pegar uma parte só e depois

```
implode()
```

mas isso não deu certo porque ficou todo desconfigurado o texto. Se alguém puder ajudar. Meu site esta usando Laravel PHP

Comment: Ideia: você pode usar substring, mas tem que descobrir antes onde a palavra acaba. Você pode pensar numa função assim "quero uns 200 caracteres, se no 200º caractere eu estiver no meio de uma palavra, pegue um pouco mais de caracteres até chegar no fim da palavra e me retorne o índice disso". Com este índice você consegue chamar a substr. Talvez você ache o `regex` útil para isso, mas não precisa.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strlen($string) > 100){
    $string = substr($string, 0, 100) . " <a href='#'>Leia Mais ...</a>";
    echo $string;
} else {
    echo $string;
}
```

Troque a Variável **String** para a sua Variável.
O Valor 100 é o número de Caracteres que sera permitido aparece na aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

**usando Jquery**

Você poderia **criar uma div com o conteúdo de "ler mais",** passar um ID pra ela, e então, primeiramente setar ela como hide (escondida), que pode ser com a classe **hiddendiv do bootstrap** ou **hide do jquery**:

```
<script>$('#id_do_conteudo_do_ler_mais').hide()</script>
```

logo depois:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#id_do_ler_mais', function() {
 $('#id_do_conteudo_do_ler_mais').show() //isso vai exibir no click do ler mais
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da versão do **laravel** que você está utilizando, existe um helper para isso chamado de `str_limit()`. Mais informações [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#strings)

```
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s';

echo str_limit( $text, 20 );
```

Essa função vai "printar" apenas os 20 primeiros caracteres e automaticamente no final da string é adicionado o "..."